# How to avoid linker error

Tags: c++, namespaces, linker-errors

Inside General.h

```
#ifndef GENERAL
#define GENERAL
namespace counternamespace{
    int upperbound;
    int lowerbound;
}
#endif
```

Inside Analyzer.h

```
#ifndef ANALYZER
#define ANALYZER
#include"General.h"

class Analyzer
{
public :
     int var ;
     int func();
};
#endif
```

Inside Test.h

```
#ifndef TEST
#define TEST
#include"Analyzer.h" //Error
class Test2
{
public:
    Test2(void);

public:
    ~Test2(void);
};
#endif
```

In the above code when I don't add Analyzer inside `Test.h` everything is working fine. But after adding its showing the following linker error.

```
1>Test2.obj : error LNK2005: "int counternamespace::lowerbound" (?lowerbound@counternamespace@@3HA) already defined in Analyzer.obj
2>Test2.obj : error LNK2005: "int counternamespace::upperbound" (?upperbound@counternamespace@@3HA) already defined in Analyzer.obj
```

I have added the `#ifndef`/`#endif`. Then where I am doing the mistake? Can anyone please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Inside General.h

#ifndef GENERAL
#define GENERAL
namespace counternamespace{
    extern int upperbound;
    extern int lowerbound;
}
#endif

Inside General.cpp

#include"General.h"
using namespace counternamespace ;
int counternamepace::upperbound = 12;
int counternamepace::lowerbound = 12;
```

Then do whatever needed .

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, Alok has right. You presumably have Analyser.cpp and Test2.cpp, both are different compilation units. When you call

```
g++ Analyser.cpp Test2.cpp
```

the compiler actually makes Analyser.obj and Test2.obj separately and links them together.
When the compiler tries to link Analyser.obj and Test2.obj together it realises that the two variables in Test2.obj are present in Analyser.obj too.

Your `#define` directives do not work since they are present only in a single compilation unit, so General.h is included *both* in Analyser.obj and Test2.obj.

To avoid such duplicates, [the solution is wrapping your namespace variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13893423/1031191) around with a function. It goes like this:

Inside General.h

```
#ifndef GENERAL
#define GENERAL
namespace counternamespace{
    int& upperbound();
    int& lowerbound();
}
#endif
```

inside General.cpp

```
#include "General.h"
namespace counternamespace{
  int& upperbound(){static int local; return local;}
  int& lowerbound(){static int local; return local;}
}
```

So you can say now

```
counternamespace::upperbound()=3;
counternamespace::lowerbound()=1;
```

and it means the same as you would have said

```
counternamespace::upperbound = 3;
counternamespace::lowerbound = 1;
```

don't worry, the compiler will optimise away the function call so there is no overhead either.

Comment: Thanks the error is gone now . But how can i access the counternamespace inside Analyzer .I am not able to access counternamespace now .

Comment: @Learner: You access `counternamespace` just like before. Nothing has changed, except for the additional parentheses after `upperbound` and `lowerbound`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not define any variables in header files.
A copy of the variables gets created in each translation unit When you include the header file in other files, thus violating the **one definition rule** and resulting in linking errors.

Comment: :Ok . Leave about Test2.h file . Inside Analyzer.h too General .h has been included . So in this case there shall be some linker error because of namespace definition both inside Analyzer and General translation unit . But its not showing any linker error . Can you please clarify on this ?

Comment: @Learner You have Analyser.cpp and Test2.cpp, both are different compilation units.

Comment: I've added details on this and a solution into my answer.