# When are global variables created?

Tags: c++, initialization

I have a piece of code structured like this:

```
a.cpp:  
    #include "b.hpp"  
    const unsigned a =  create(1);


b.cpp:
    map<int, string> something; // global variable
    unsigned create(unsigned a){
        something.insert(make_pair(a, "somestring"));
        return a;
    }
```

Now, this throws out a segfault, valgrind says that map was not yet created. How does it work, how should I change it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++ does not define an order for when global variables are constructed during program startup. `a` could be initialized first before `something` gets constructed which would cause the problem above. When you start constructing global variables that depend on other global variables being initialized then you run into the classical *static initialization order fiasco*.

An easy way to fix your above scenario is to make `something` static and move it into your `create` function.

```
unsigned create(unsigned a)
{
    static map<int, string> something;
    something.insert(make_pair(a, "somestring"));
    return a;
}
```

That will guarantee `something` gets created on first call to `create`.

Comment: But `static map<int, string> something;`  is now local inside the function and not accessible outside then ?

Answer (score 9):

All global variables are created before entering the main(), but their order of construction between different translation units is not specified by the c++ standard. Their order of construction within the same translation unit is in order of specification.

You could form something that is guarantied by the standard. Something like this :

```
map<int, string>& mymap(){
    static map<int, string> something;
    return something;
}

unsigned create( unsigned a ) {
    mymap().insert(make_pair(a, "somestring"));
    return a;
}
```

The map something is created the first time function mymap() is called.

Comment: Global variables within each translation unit are constructed in order of their declaration. The order **between** translation units is, indeed, not specified.

Comment: They're not even required to be "constructed" (dynamically initialized) before entering `main`, see [basic.start.init]/4. To add further complication, static data member of not explicitly specialized class templates have unordered initialization, everything else has ordered initialization (within a TU).

Answer (score 3):

The order, in which global variables from different translation units (i.e. located in different *.cpp files) are initialized is not defined by the standard. Thus, relying on it is `undefined behaviour`. See also:

- [C++ global initialization order ignores dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746238/c-global-initialization-order-ignores-dependencies/3746249#3746249)
- [Static variables initialisation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211237/static-variables-initialisation-order/211307#211307)

Answer (score 2):

The order in which global variables (that is, variables at namespace scope) is created is specified at being:

- the order in which they appear, in a translation unit
- unspecified, from one translation unit to another

This is something that languages with modules do not suffer, but unfortunately a common issue in C++. Using function-local static variables, one can get initialization on first use, which generally solves this issue.

Example of static local:

```
int func(int a) {
    static std::map<int, int> m;
    return m[a] = m.size();
}
```

Comment: "the order in which they appear, in a translation unit" unless they're static data members of not explicitly specialized class templates (for dynamic initialization).