# Is there anyway to order static object initialization of difference class (difference file)

Tags: c++, initialization

WORKSPACE_A.cpp/.h

```
Class WORKSPACE_A {
   static AAA a;
}
```

WORKSPACE_B.cpp/.h

```
   Class WORKSPACE_B {
       static BBB b;
    }
```

How do I know whether AAA a , or BBB b is initialized first.

Thank you

Comment: you can't, you shouldn't care (you should just imagine that they are initialized at the same time)

Comment: @Exceptyon Perhaps BBB b; has to call WORKSPACE_A:a in BBB::BBB() constructor

Comment: You should initialize the static variables in a cpp-file in any order you need. For example, `int WORKSPACE_A::a = 1; int WORKSPACE_B::b = 2;`. Also you may move all initialization in a method and use `#pragma`s to run it at initialization. The pragmas may vary depending from your compiler: `#pragma startup` and `#pragma init_seg` are to name a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the ["static initialization order fiasco"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html)

A common approach is to use initialize-on-first-use within an "accessor function"

```
class WORKSPACE_A {

   AAA& getA()
   {
     static AAA a;
     return a;
   }
}
```

Of course, you still have "static destruction order fiasco" to contend with... This can be mitigated by dynamically allocating the AAA in the accessor (`static AAA *a = new AAA;`) but then the object simply *never* gets destructed!

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Denny the issue is probably dependencies between the twos.

I think the way to go is having pointers and explicit static init functions:

```
class WORKSPACE_A {
   static AAA* a;
public:
   static void initialize() { /* a = ... */ }
}

class WORKSPACE_B {
   static BBB* b;
public:
   static void initialize() { /* b = some_f(WORKSPACE::a) */ }
}
```

Comment: I know it could be fixed by your above code , that's no way to order initialzation right ? , can I order file when linking *.o ("cc workspace_a.o workspace_b.o to solve this problem ?

Comment: could be... depends on how your linker is implemented I guess... I wouldn't rely on that anyway: one day you'll forget to order the .o in a makefile, or change compiler

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

The standard says that this is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Order of initialization of global variables (or static) are guaranteed in each translation unit. But not guaranteed in different translation units.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3746249/231388) to the question [C++ global initialization order ignores dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746238/c-global-initialization-order-ignores-dependencies/3746249#3746249).