# C++ initialization of namespace scope variable

Tags: c++, initialization, global-variables, unspecified-behavior

Consider following program: (see live demo [here.](http://ideone.com/ptxbtS))

```
#include <iostream>
inline double fun()
{
    return 3.0;
}
extern double m;
double d2=m;
int main()
{
    std::cout<<d2;
}
double m=fun();
```

I was expecting to get output of program as 3.0 but it gives me output 0. Why?

It looks like variable d2 is initialized statically?

Shouldn't it be initialized dynamically?

I've tested it on g++ 4.8.1, 4.9.2 & MSVS 2010 & get 0 as an output.

Comment: `It looks like variable d2 is initialized statically?` Sort of. Both `d2` and `m` are initialized to 0 first thing when the program loads. Then `d2` is initialized from `m` (which is still 0). Finally, `m` is initialized from `fun()`.

Comment: Why is that? You are printing `d2`, not `m`. If you have `int x = 0; int y = x; x = 42;`, do you expect `y` to be retroactively set to 42 also?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22117407/1413133) will be of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables within a `C++` file are initialized top-to-bottom.  So `m` is initialized after `d`.

There are some other subtleties.

When the compiler can work it out, it sometimes emits data definitions for variables - setting a value to a known constant.  These occur before the program is loaded.

Then the order of initialization is the code segments - like constructors.  These segments occur top to bottom in the compilation unit.

In your case `d=m` I think copies the value from the slot for m.  Which is set to 0.0

Then `m=fun()` is called, copying the slot with the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both `d2` and `m` have static storage duration, because they are declared, undecorated, at namespace scope.

That means they are *zero-initialised* as a first step before any other initialisation happens. Then, `d2` is set to `m`. It is not until *after* that, that `m` becomes `3.0`.

Consider the following, which is essentially the same thing:

```
int main()
{
   int x = 0, y = 0;
   y = x;
   x = 3;
}
```

Clearly, here, it is nonsense to expect `y` to be equal to `3`, but that's what you're doing.

If you expected the initialisation to happen like for function-`static` variables, where initialisation happens on first use (*sort of*), you were mistaken.

Comment: @PravasiMeet: No, I cannot prove a negative. Instead, why don't you explain why this simple answer is "still wrong" and why you "not agree"?

Comment: @PravasiMeet: Either you _didn't_, or you lied earlier about having downvoted in the first place. This answer has only ever had one, and it's still there.

Comment: @Pravasi: Right, another proof that you did not remove your downvote, contrary to your claim. Full of lies today :(