# Are global variables always initialized prior to any global thread_local variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, global-variables, thread-local-storage

```
struct A
{
    A() : n(1)
    {}

    int n;
};

struct B
{
    B() : n(2)
    {}

    int n;
};

thread_local A a;
B b;

int main()
{
    return a.n;
}
```

`a` is defined before `b`.

My question:

**Does the C++ standard guarantee `B::B()` is called before `A::A()` is called?**

Comment: Not 100% sure because of `thread_local` so related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746238/c-global-initialization-order-ignores-dependencies/3746249#3746249

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization